# How to save results of each iteration of GridSearchCV to Excel file and print each combination of hyperparameters with mean AUC?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lstm, gridsearchcv

I have code to make GridSearchCV for tuning of hyperparameters in LSTM in Python like below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
#from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam


def build_lstm_model(units, dropout_rate, learning_rate):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), dropout=dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))  
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate), metrics=['AUC'])

    return model

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_lstm_model, epochs=20, verbose=4)
param_grid = {'units': [16, 32, 64, 128]
              , 'dropout_rate': [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]
              , 'learning_rate': [0.001, 0.01]}
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=5, verbose = 4)
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And I have 2 questions:

1. How to save results of each combinations of hyperparameters to Excel file. I would like to have in that file: number of iteration, hyperparameters used in that iteration, average AUC from 5 folds
2. How to print in each iteration: number of iteration, hyperparameters used in that iteration, average AUC from 5 folds

How can I modify my code in Python ?